# Get item as soon as it inserted in dynamodb in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Looking for example
We insert single record in dynamodb
We need to retrieve that item as soon as it inserted in dynamodb database using python

Just like get record seeking continuously for latest item in db once it inserted it will retrieved from db

Comment: Use dynamodb streams.

Comment: You typically want an event-based solution without having to poll the database which means using [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) and [Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) functions, but you can also write a Python client that [polls streams](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodbstreams.html).

Comment: @jarmod That seems like an answer, why not add it as such? :)

Comment: @Maurice I didn't want to steal the opportunity to answer for luk2302 but yes, agree, so I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically want an event-based solution without having to poll the database which means using [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) and [Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) functions.

You can, however, also write a Python client that [polls DynamoDB Streams](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodbstreams.html).

Comment: I have done this but in first execution i got data record but after terminate python program i got error KeyError: 'NextShardIterator'                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                     
                      response = client.get_records(ShardIterator=shard_iterator, Limit=1)

Comment: You should create a new post and include the minimal code needed to illustrate the problem. Maybe the documentation is incorrect and rather than NextShardIterator being null, which is what the docs say, it is simply absent if there's no continuation?

Comment: response sharedit-- {'Records': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '74a9ea37-9a97-41d0-9a46-9dc526b2b27c', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Mon, 23 May 2022 14:22:18 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0', 'x-amz-crc32': '2531396130', 'x-amzn-requestid': '74a9ea37-9a97-41d0-9a46-9dc526b2b27c', 'content-length': '14', 'server': 'Jetty(9.4.18.v20190429)'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}

Comment: Thanks for adding the response. Given that the `Records` list is empty, I'd say that the boto3 docs are misleading at best. I think you should change your code to first of all test `if NextShardIterator in response:` to handle it being absent.