# Aws DynamoDb Stream for NextShardIterator key in response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb-streams

i am using dynamodbstream
calling with  method
response = client.get_records(ShardIterator=shard_iterator, Limit=1)

initially response contain response['NextShardIterator'] key

but after some time I got KeyError: 'NextShardIterator'
why it is absent in response

Comment: As indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72290805/get-item-as-soon-as-it-inserted-in-dynamodb-in-python), I think the boto3 docs are misleading. Change your code to first of all test `if NextShardIterator in response:` to handle it being absent. You might also consider raising an issue against the boto3 docs.

Comment: thnx jarmod its solve my problem

Comment: @jarmod is arn stream has lifetime? because after 2-3 hr after terminate code if I tryied then it give me null respose without NextShardIterator

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_GetShardIterator.html): "A shard iterator expires 15 minutes after it is returned to the requester." But DynamoDB Streams captures and stores change data for up to 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing code like the following:

```
shard_iterator = response['NextShardIterator']

if not shard_iterator:
    break
```

Write the following instead:

```
if 'NextShardIterator' in response:
    shard_iterator = response['NextShardIterator']
else:
    break
```

Or you can use dict.get with a default value, as follows:

```
shard_iterator = response.get('NextShardIterator', None)

if not shard_iterator:
    break
```